# Disable Android Button When Edit Text (parsing value) Empty

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-edittext

I have 2 fields and a button. I want to disable the button when the fields are empty. I've tried many solutions but still doesn't work. Here my code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   

@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String p1 =
                    edtP.getText().toString().trim();
            String l2 =
                    edtL.getText().toString().trim();

            double dp = Double.parseDouble(p1);
            double dl = Double.parseDouble(l2);

            double total = dp * dl;

            txtT.setText("equals: " +total);

            if (  ( !p1.trim().isEmpty()) && ( !l2.trim().isEmpty()) ) {

                btnCount.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    }); }
```

Every time I run the project, I always get this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   

@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
if(edtP.getText().toString().length()>0 &&  edtL.getText().toString().length()>0){
            String p1 =
                    edtP.getText().toString().trim();
            String l2 =
                    edtL.getText().toString().trim();

            double dp = Double.parseDouble(p1);
            double dl = Double.parseDouble(l2);

            double total = dp * dl;

            txtT.setText("equals: " +total);

           if (  !(p1.trim().isEmpty()) && ( !l2.trim().isEmpty()) ) {

                    btnCount.setEnabled(true);
                }
    else{
    btnCount.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
else{
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Edittexts are empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
        }
    }); }
```

Comment: i've tried your code and its works, but i still get an error if i only fill 1 editText. I'll try to change your code and i'll report later.

Comment: Ohh, my bad i'm sorry. Your code is works great, i was setup wrong a variable so it still caused the error but the problem was solved, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add textChange listener to both of your fields and in the onTextChanged Method of both fields, Check if text provided is empty or not. If empty disable the button else enable the button.

```
Field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0 && Field2.getText().toString.length()!=0){
        // enable the button
      }else{
        // disable the button
      }
   }
  });

Field2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0 && Field1.getText().toString.length()!=0){
        // enable the button
      }else{
        // disable the button
      }
   }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   

@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String p1 =  edtP.getText().toString().trim();
            String l2 =  edtL.getText().toString().trim();
            double dp = 0, dl = 0, total = 0;
            try{
              dp = Double.parseDouble(p1);
              dl = Double.parseDouble(l2);
              total = dp * dl;
              txtT.setText("equals: " +total);
            }catch(Exception e){
              dp = -1;
              dl = -1;
              btnCount.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: i've tried your solutions but didn't work, i will try again your code later because i'm trying @Aakash code now